# Handling errors when variable is null - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm querying a model in a method in my controller to get all messages.

```
public function index(){

        $messages = Message::where('sender_id', Auth::user()->id)->orWhere('recipient_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

        return view('/pages/message/index', compact('messages'));
    }
```

If the model is null and has now entries, I get an error of 'can get method of non object or something like that.

What's the best way to handle errors like this. Ideallly in the controller

Comment: you could write an `if`-statement or use the [optional helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional)

Comment: if($messages ){ 
$messages = []
}

so it will not error on your blade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@if($messages)
    //Codes
@endif
```

if collection in loop. **Forelse** statement is cool for that.

```
@forelse ($messages as $message)
    <li>{{ $message->content }}</li>
@empty
    <p>There is no messages</p>
@endforelse
```

Comment: Thanks. Would just be in the controller, or view

Comment: it must be in the view. Also you can do it controller, but if its null you can't pass to controller. It is so complicated and want a lot of performance. View is cool. But the right way is @if(!empty($messages))
instead of @if($messages)

Answer (score 1):

in your view

```
@if(count($messages)>0)
//your code
@endif
```

or

```
@if(!empty($messages))
//your code
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: you can do in controller also
if($messages){
  //your code
}else{
  $messages = []; //sending blank array
}

@JackSmith12

Comment: No, why do you say that?